# xcode objective x framework code folding

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, code-folding

I am looking at trying to write my own simple html / php text editor, one of the features is code-folding / collapsible rows based on open { and close } ( please wiki lookup code-folding if you do not know what I mean )

I will be writing this application in Xcode for the Mac OS X platform.

I have tried google to find examples or frameworks for code-folding but I keep getting information about how to code-fold in xcode the application when what I want to know is how to actually create a code-folding in a text field.

if anyone knows a good resource or framework, please let me know.

thanks in advance.